# Delaying kernel upgrades on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, linux-kernel, upgrade

On Arch Linux, whenever a kernel upgrade is applied (via `pacman -Su`), problems occur. For example, `iptables` can no longer be used:

```
# iptables -L
iptables v1.4.21: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

VMWare can't find the kernel headers:

[image]

Now, I want to have kernel upgrades applied, but I'd like to defer them until I can (or want to) restart the system (remind anyone of Windows?). Otherwise, if my work is blocked on `iptables` or VMWare or some other program, I have no choice but to restart and rebuild a session.

How can I do that? Ideally I'd like to continue using `pacman -Su`, but have certain upgrades deferred.

I believe [Is it normal that a restart is required to mount USB after a kernel upgrade?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30100/is-it-normal-that-a-restart-is-required-to-mount-usb-after-a-kernel-upgrade) is caused by the same problem.

Comment: Running `pacman -Su` is going to fail often; always use `pacman -Syu`...

Comment: @jasonwryan That was the concise version. What I actually run is: `alias pacu='pacaur -Syu'`

Answer (score 11):

If you want to keep `pacman` from up/down grading some package(s), you put a line in `/etc/pacman.conf`:

```
# Pacman won't upgrade packages listed in IgnorePkg and members of IgnoreGroup
#IgnorePkg   =
#IgnoreGroup =
```

I think you want to have a line like this in `pacman.conf`:

```
IgnorePkg = linux linux-headers linux-api-headers
```

As you point out, that just keeps `pacman` from any upgrading.  You could probably write some code like this:

```
if pacman -Qu | egrep -q -s 'linux|linux-headers|linux-api-headers'
then
    pacman -S --noconfirm linux
    pacman -S --noconfirm linux-headers
    pacman -S --noconfirm linux-api-headers
fi
```

It looks like you have to write a "[systemd unit file](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=188858)" - that part's a bit beyond what I have confidence in telling you what to do. My thought is that the `Before=shutdown.target` line in the unit file is what makes it run at shutdown. The only unit file I wrote took me several tries to get correct, so I really don't think you want my advice on that.

Comment: That would completely stop `pacman` from upgrading those packages unless I explicitly told it to. So how do I do that automatically before reboot if there's an upgrade available?

Comment: @muru - see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll  look into systemd units. They can't be that much harder than Upstart jobs, hopefully. (Possible typo in the second code block: `linx` instead of `linux`.)

Answer (score 2):

To skip upgrading the kernel, you can run:

`pacman -Syu --ignore linux,linux-headers,linux-api-headers`

This will allow you to upgrade everything **except** the kernel

Answer (score -1):

I think that `linux-api-headers` package should not be ignored for motive

**Don't upgrade my kernel Or Ignore my kernel upgrade and also don't upgrade any package that will break the system if it alone is upgraded and kernel is not**

See this [answer](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1925274#p1925274) on arch wiki forum.

What I did
`IgnorePkg = linux linux-headers virtualbox-host-modules-arch`

Only ignore `virtualbox-host-modules-arch` pkg if you have VirtualBox installed. Same for `linux-headers` pkg. Since I had both of them installed I did this.